c++ - determine if executable that includes __DATE__, __TIME__ has changed
I am compiling dozens of executables in my Git project and I need a way to determine if a given one has actually changed so I can deploy only the changed ones.
Simple solution is to hash the exe but some of the them use __DATE__, __TIME__ macros so the exe changes every build.
Besides hashing the source + headers + compiler + environment ... etc, is there a way to determine if the generated code is different?

Why not just inspect git history if sources has been changed?

@MarekR You need to examine the entire dependency chain for each executable.

You know which binaries are build from which sources, and you should have a change set of changed sources. So basically you already have all the information you need.

Well not all, when your package dependencies have changed, you can still have new binaries (due to linking) so it is not only your sources.  Also you might want to limit the number of binaries you build from one package and split your installer into smaller parts.

If your goal is "reproducible builds" then you are going to need to ban the use of the 2 macros.

Linux distributions like Nix and Guix spent a lot of effort to set up build environments in such a way that identical sources will produce identical outputs even if these macros, or many other constructs that could affect the output non-deterministically, are present. They also both double as generic package managers. Maybe have a look at them, either to see how they handle this, or to simply use them for your purpose. Ultimately they decide whether the output would change by hashing all  build inputs recursively.

Even if you don't use these macros, some compilers automatically put the compilation time in the ELF header.

Since __DATE__ and __TIME__ are macros, they're constexpr values and you can generate arbitrarily different programs from the same source code. What you probably need is to compare the binaries themselves.

something like build id? https://docs.redhat.com/en/documentation/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/developer_guide/compiling-build-id
